# Terraform - Azure Key Vault Secrets creation not idempotent

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-keyvault, terraform-provider-azure

On the first terraform apply, this configuration currently successfully creates a key vault and populates secrets from a list "secrets" with values created with the random resource.

Everytime this configuration is run thereafter throws this error:
│** Error**: A resource with the ID "https://testingkeyvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/Password1/3e4cdc60c7e12345a228fd4250b58191" already exists - to be managed via Terraform this resource needs to be imported into the State. Please see the resource documentation for "azurerm_key_vault_secret" for more information.

```
variable "secrets" {
  type = list(string)
  default = [
  "Password1",
  "Password2",
  "Password3",
  "Password4"
]
}

data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {
  provider = azurerm.PlatformManagement
}

data "azurerm_key_vault" "existing" {
  provider            = azurerm.PlatformManagement
  name                = var.KeyVaultName
  resource_group_name = var.KeyVault_Rg_Name
  depends_on          = [azurerm_key_vault.pman-vault]
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault" "pman-vault" {
  provider = azurerm.PlatformManagement

  name                        = var.KeyVaultName
  location                    = var.Location
  resource_group_name         = var.KeyVault_Rg_Name
  enabled_for_disk_encryption = true
  tenant_id                   = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  soft_delete_retention_days  = 7
  purge_protection_enabled    = false
  sku_name                    = "standard"
  enable_rbac_authorization   = true

data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "existing-secrets" {
  count               = length(var.secrets)
  name                = var.secrets[count.index]
  key_vault_id        = azurerm_key_vault.pman-vault.id
  depends_on          = [azurerm_key_vault_secret.pman-secrets]
}

resource "random_password" "password" {
  count            = var.create_secrets ? length(var.secrets) : 0
  length           = 15
  special          = true
  override_special = "!@#$%&*()-_=+[]{}<>:?"
}

 resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "pman-secrets" {
   count        = var.create_secrets ? length(var.secrets) : 0
   name         = var.secrets[count.index]
   value        = random_password.password[count.index].result
   key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.pman-vault.id
   lifecycle {
     prevent_destroy = true
   }
   depends_on = [azurerm_key_vault.pman-vault]
 }
```

The result I'm looking for is for it to be able to detect the passwords that it has already created and exists in the keyvault and for the terraform code to run idempotently. What am I doing wrong and what can I do to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to provision the Terraform - Azure Key Vault Secrets creation, not idempotent I was able to provision the requirement successfully.

The problem with your Terraform configuration is that you are using a `count` attribute on the `azurerm_key_vault_secret` resource without specifying a `for_each` argument. This means that Terraform will create a new secret for each item in the `secrets` variable, even if the secret already exists in the Key Vault.

To make your Terraform configuration idempotent, you need to use a `for_each` argument to specify which data source to iterate over when creating the secrets. In this case, you want to iterate over the `azurerm_key_vault_secret.existing-secrets` data source.

Here is a modified version of your Terraform configuration that is idempotent:

**My terraform configuration:**

```
provider "azurerm" {
    features {}
}
  
  variable "secrets" {
  type = list(string)
  default = [
    "Password1",
    "Password2",
    "Password3",
    "Password4"
  ]
}

variable "KeyVaultName" {
  description = "Name of the KeyVault"
  default     = "demovksbvaultvk"
}

variable "KeyVault_Rg_Name" {
  description = "Resource Group of the KeyVault"
  default     = "v-sakavya"
}

variable "Location" {
  description = "Azure region for the KeyVault"
  default     = "East US"
}

data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}



data "azurerm_key_vault" "existing" {
  name                = var.KeyVaultName
  resource_group_name = var.KeyVault_Rg_Name
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault" "pman-vault" {
  count                       = data.azurerm_key_vault.existing.id != null ? 0 : 1
  name                        = var.KeyVaultName
  location                    = var.Location
  resource_group_name         = var.KeyVault_Rg_Name
  tenant_id                   = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  sku_name                    = "standard"
  soft_delete_retention_days  = 7
  purge_protection_enabled    = false
}

resource "random_password" "password" {
  count            = length(var.secrets)
  length           = 15
  special          = true
  override_special = "!@#$%&*()-_=+[]{}<>:?"
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "pman-secrets" {
  for_each = toset(var.secrets)

  name         = each.value
  value        = random_password.password[index(var.secrets, each.value)].result
  key_vault_id = length(azurerm_key_vault.pman-vault) > 0 ? azurerm_key_vault.pman-vault[0].id : data.azurerm_key_vault.existing.id

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [value]
    prevent_destroy = true
  }
}

data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "fetched_secrets" {
  for_each = toset(var.secrets)
  name         = each.value
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.existing.id
}

output "fetched_secrets_values" {
  value = { for s in var.secrets : s => lookup(data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.fetched_secrets[s], "value", null) }
  description = "The fetched secret values from Azure Key Vault."
  sensitive = true
}
```

**Output:**

##### `Terraform apply:`

[image]

[image]

Repeating the command again

##### `Terraform apply:`

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for the help! I am new to Terraform so really appreciate it. This has mostly worked, I have ran into another issue with this as it only works when the KeyVault already exists with the same name in the same resource group. If the KeyVault isn't already there it will come up with an error  │ Error: Key Vault (Subscription: ""
│ Resource Group Name: "testingrg"
│ Key Vault Name: "testingvault") was not found
The count argument on the Vault creation should detect whether the keyvault already exists and creates if it doesn't right?

Comment: The error occur because Terraform is trying to fetch details of the KeyVault using the data "azurerm_key_vault" "existing" block before the KeyVault is created in your code

try adding 

locals {
  existing_kv_id = try(data.azurerm_key_vault.existing.id, null)
}

because Same code mentioned in solution works perfectly for me as per the requirement